Map variable becomes null when manipulated as part of a Jenkins pipeline
I'm building a Jenkins pipeline, and I have this method:
private Map processServerMapping(Map serverMapping, List newVersions) {
    def currentVersions = serverMapping.values().toSet()
    def removedVersions = currentVersions - newVersions.toSet()
    if (removedVersions) {
        def newVersionsToAssign = newVersions - currentVersions
        def serversToClear = []
        serverMapping.each { server, version ->
            if (removedVersions.contains(version)) {
                serversToClear.add(server)
            }
        }
        serversToClear.each { server ->
          serverMapping[server] = null
        }
        def availableServers = serverMapping.findAll { it.value == null }.keySet()
        newVersionsToAssign.eachWithIndex { version, index ->
            if (index < availableServers.size()) {
                serverMapping[availableServers[index]] = version
            }
        }
    }
    return serverMapping
}

The purpose is to assign versions to servers, and keep this mapping up to date as new versions get released.
When I call it like this in the Jenkins script console:
Map currentMapping = ["bm05-ibm":"4.16.0", "bm06-ibm":"4.15.3"]
List nearestReleases = ["4.14.7", "4.17.0"]
processServerMapping(currentMapping,nearestReleases)

This is what I get: Result: {bm05-ibm=4.14.7, bm06-ibm=4.17.0}
So, works as expected.
However, when I call this function within a Jenkins pipeline, this function returns null.
I added prints to debug this:
        echo "processServerMapping:serverMappingBeforeClear = ${serverMapping}"
        serverMapping.each { server, version ->
            if (removedVersions.contains(version)) {
                serversToClear.add(server)
            }
        }
        serversToClear.each { server ->
          serverMapping[server] = null
        }
        echo "processServerMapping:serverMappingAfterClear = ${serverMapping}" 

And these are the prints in the pipeline:
11:26:53 [Pipeline] echo

11:26:53 processServerMapping:serverMappingBeforeClear = [bm05-ibm:4.16.0, bm06-ibm:4.15.3]

11:26:53 [Pipeline] echo

11:26:53 processServerMapping:serverMappingAfterClear = [:]

It seems that serverMapping[server] = null  is nullifying the entire map, I don't know why.
Why is the behavior different between the script console and the actual pipeline?
I tried manipulating the Map within the iterator, keeping it in a separate variable to maintain scope, but none of these things seem to have effect.

I have just tried running your code and it works as expected. There is something you are not telling us :)

@Iterokun I'm perplexed by this. Works as expected, until you call this function in a pipeline

I ran it in a pipeline

https://pastebin.com/P4fR7x6F see my version here. what are you doing differently?

In my case, the method is stored in /vars/
That should make no difference though
Also, nearestReleases is generated by another method, so I'll try and eliminate that variable as well. But whether that list is OK or not, I don't see why the entire map would become null

OK OK. What I haven't been telling you - the currentMapping variable that I pass to this method contains a Map object that was returned by a readJSON statement. When I provide the Map statically, it works OK, but misbehaves when retrieved through readJSON. I'm looking into alternatives.

Yup, replaced readJSON with good old jsonSlurper and it works great. Thank you for being my rubber duck

You can still use the readJSON step, just pass the returnPojo: true parameter.

Transforms the output into a POJO type (LinkedHashMap or ArrayList) before returning it. By default deactivated (false), and a JSON object (JSONObject or JSONArray from json-lib) is returned.

And JSONObject indeed does some unintuitive stuff.
